# How do I read a XML spreadsheet which has .xls suffix in python?

Tags: python, xml

I have a excel extract, the file is named with a .xls suffix. But this file is actually a XML Spreadsheet. I am struggling to read this in python for my analysis. Within this file there are 3 sheets, I need to specifically read sheetname ="sheetname3"

I have tried couple things like the below.

1- Attempted t use pd.read_excel with openpyxl engine.

```
kpath = os.path.join(r"F:\DOCUMENT\Treasury\Test\K vs Clearer", 'REC_IRSOIS_' +  DATE + '.xls')

df = pd.read_excel(kpath, sheet_name ="sheetname3", engine="openpyxl")
```

2- Below I tried to convert this Excel XML file programmatically but not sure how to specify a sheet name here.

```
class ExcelHandler(ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.chars = [  ]
        self.cells = [  ]
        self.rows = [  ]
        self.tables = [  ]
    def characters(self, content):
        self.chars.append(content)
    def startElement(self, name, atts):
        if name=="Cell":
            self.chars = [  ]
        elif name=="Row":
            self.cells=[  ]
        elif name=="Table":
            self.rows = [  ]
    def endElement(self, name):
        if name=="Cell":
            self.cells.append(''.join(self.chars))
        elif name=="Row":
            self.rows.append(self.cells)
        elif name=="Table":
            self.tables.append(self.rows)
            
excelHandler = ExcelHandler()
parse(kpath, excelHandler, sheet_name= "IRS & OIS Reconciliation Output")
```

Comment: what happens when you read it `pandas`?

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused about *xml* and *xls*. If the file is an *XML*, why don't you read it using *pd.read\_**xml***?

Comment: @CristiFati, I guess OP means it's xlsx file, with xls extension. But you are right it's unclear

Comment: The file has .xls in the name so it doesn't work.

Comment: when I try read it pandas, I get error BadZipFile: File is not a zip file. df = pd.read_excel(kpath, header=None, engine="openpyxl")

Comment: That means it's not xlsx file, despite what you think. It may be corrupt or something

Answer (score 0):

`openpyxl` is not able to open legacy `.xls` files, it is meant for newer XLSX/XLSM files ([docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)).

Use the correct engine ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html))

```py
df = pd.read_excel(kpath, sheet_name ="sheetname3", engine="xlrd")
```

Or just leave the engine empty and pandas will use the correct one for your filetype.

```py
df = pd.read_excel(kpath, sheet_name ="sheetname3")
```

Comment: Thanks but it gives me XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<?xml ve'

Comment: Then, your file is neither XLS nor XLSX, where did you get it from ?

Comment: So I got told by IT that the file is actually a XML but the file name will have .xls , my file name is REC_DATA_2023_01_18.xls , when I open the file I get a message that file format and extension does not match. Not sure what to do here

Comment: You do seem to have an XML file give the `<?xml ve` you posted above, that's the beginning of an XML declaration, however without seeing the contents of that file, I cannot help you more. Have you tried opening with [`pandas.read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

I just used the Excel handler code I provided and manually moved the tab to first position.